# Passing managed class object to c++ dll

Tags: c++, managed

I am having a dll in which I have some managed classes. I need to set the attribute values of managed class from the .exe and pass it to the dll. But dllexport function doesnt accept the managed class as parameter. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What is the error you are receiving when you try to `dllexport` the managed class?

Comment: @selalerer  __declspec(dllexport) cannot be applied to a function with the __clrcall calling convention. It is in documentation.

Comment: Pretty unclear why you'd expect a *class* to work when trying to export a function.  Show your code.

Comment: @Fresher So don't use __clrcall. AFAIK it is not mandatory, it is just an optimization.

Comment: @HansPassant can i export managed class itself ?

Comment: I'd guess you already discovered the answer to that question.  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score -1):

If your .dll is "plain" dll (not some COM class or .NET assembly), you cannot expose classes. You can, however expose something like

```
void* CreateInstance(int param1, const char* param2);
int DoSomeMegaWork(void* instance, const int* paramZ);
```

Implementation will be
    void* CreateInstance(param1, param2)
    {
        YourClass* instance = new YourClass(param1);
        //well, whenever
        instance.DoSomeWork(param2);
        return instance;
    }

```
int DoSomeMegaWork(void* _instance, const int* paramZ)
{
    YoutClass* instance = (YourClass*) _instance;
    return instance.DoSomeMegaWork(paramZ);
}
```

Don't forget to destroy instances in the same .dll